# Docker setting an ENV variable from docker-compose.yml

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a simple case where I try to pass a variable (ultimately an ENV variable) from my `docker-compose`. It doesn't seem to work right now and I've no idea where's the bug.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  sprintbotmanager:
    container_name: sprintbotmanager
    image: sprintbotmanager:latest
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REACT_APP_API_URL="aabbcc"
    volumes:
      - "/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    depends_on:
      - sprintbotserver
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    stdin_open: true
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10

MAINTAINER Kuba Wasilewski <jakub.wasilewski@sprint.pl>
 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install
 
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_URL ${REACT_APP_API_URL}

COPY . .
 
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I just can't seem to pass my args between the `docker-compose` and my `Dockerfile`. Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to pass an enivorment variable which is needed when the container is running, but the way you pass the variable (via `args` and `ARG`) it is only available during the build process as stated in the [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args).

If I remember correctly (I haven't found documentation that states this, so I can be as well wrong), but I think that you set the `ENV` variable in the Dockerfile correctly, but it is overridden by Docker Compose environment variables.

I haven't tested this, but if this is the problem, it should work by just adding your variable to `environment` in docker-compose, like so:

```
environment:
- CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
- REACT_APP_API_URL="aabbcc"
```